# mod rewrite not working in .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am trying to write rewriterule for php site.

My URL is like `http://example.com/attorneys?pid=69`

I write in .htacess as below:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^attorneys/([0-9]+)/?$ attorneys&pid=$1 [NC,L]
```

Both the link `example.com/attorneys?pid=69` and `example.com/attorneys/69` works.

How can I make the browser know that if it get the first link it have to show the second one in browser.

Answer (score 2):

```
RewriteRule ^attorneys/([0-9]+)/?$ attorneys&pid=$1 [NC,L,R=302]
```

Comment: That does not answer his question.

Answer (score 2):

So you want to redirect `http://xyz.com/attorneys?pid=69` to `http://xyz.com/attorneys/69`? Another rule after(!) the first rule should do the trick:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^attorneys/([0-9]+)/?$ attorneys&pid=$1 [NC,L] 
RewriteRule ^attorneys&pid=([0-9]+)$ attorneys/$1 [NC,L,R=301]
```

Because the first rule is marked with the `L` flag, the second won't be executed if the first matches. (See the [documentation of mod_rewrite flags here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriteflags).)

Comment: Thanks middus, but when i add the second rule site shows me 'Internal Server Error'. Do I need to do anything else?

Answer (score 0):

First, I need to say you there is **no need** to do that. Anyway, I was forced to do it in the past for a SEO-maniac client. I tell you, that's not an elegant solution!

On top of the `attorneys` PHP page (I don't know if it's a directory with index.php or not, but you know it) add this code:

```
    // Get request script
    $request = preg_split('/[\\/?&]/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    $request_script = $request[1];

    // Check old URL
    if ($request_script == 'attorneys') {

        // Redirect
        header('Location: /attorneys/' . $_GET['id'];
        exit();

    }
```

Maybe it's not exactly like this for your case, but I hope you get the mechanism.

Comment: Why do that in php and not using mod_rewrite?

Comment: I can't get it to work. I don't know if there were problems in my Apache's `ModRewrite` configuration or not. The solution you posted made my browser do an infinite loop redirection, also using the `L` flag. Hope that Shah will not face the same problem, in the case I shared also my solution :)

Comment: Strange. Notice that the first rule may not have an 'R' flag, though. Do you think there's any conceptual difference between your php implementation and my mod_rewrite one?

Comment: Yes yes, I know the `R` flag. No, conceptually there are no differences, I agree.

Comment: Okay, so we can agree that both do the same. I think it's good to implement all this redirection stuff in one place: the .htaccess. That's why I think this issue should not even hit the php script(s). However, I don't know what the problem with your mod_rewrite is, though.

Comment: Thanks Lorenzo, I put it in index file & when i run it it goes to infinite root. Any idea?

Comment: Nope. Sorry. Try to update your answer with your current .htaccess and PHP code.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a simple ask. Try this code in your .htaccess file under DOCUMENT_ROOT (and comment out your existing code):

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
RewriteOptions MaxRedirects=5

RewriteRule ^(attorneys)/([^/]+)/?$ $1?pid=$2 [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^pid=(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(attorneys)/?$ /$1/%1? [NC,L,R=301]
```