# Htaccess change url to directory url

Tags: .htaccess

For example, I want:

http://site.com/cool.php?page=woohoo

http://site.com/cool.php?page=yoyoyo

To show this in the browser:

http://site.com/woohoo/

http://site.com/yoyoyo/

How do I do this?

Comment: Google for htaccess tutorial can give you nice examples: http://corz.org/serv/tricks/htaccess2.php

Comment: I'm afraid it's not what supercoolville is asking. He is not asking for the "standard" basic URL rewriting, but for the reverse bahaviour, I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8446690/995958

It gives a nice way to do exactly what you want to do.
Other answers are useful too if you have problems with the confirmed one.